# Fetch child data with parents in Django queries

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two Model Product and ProductBundle. ProductBundle have a foreign key of Product Model. How can I access a list of all product with there productbundle.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Product Title", max_length=500)

class ProductBundle(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="product")
    bundle_product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="bundle_product",default="")
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default="1")
```

I want to fetch all product with there productbundle ids like
parent to childs in a single variable.

Thanks.

Comment: This may can more specific to your requirement just have a look. `ProductBundle.objects.filter(product=Product.objects.get(id=object_id).id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have `ProductBundle` objects as a **[Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)** for each `Product`.

Assuming you do `products = Product.objects.all()` you can access each product's bundles by doing:

```
for product in products:
    product_bundles = product.productbundle_set.all()
```

**Edit based on comment:**

If you want to show all products with their bundles in a template you can do almost the same thing. In your `view` get all products within a variable, for example `products = Product.objects.all()` and pass it to the template. Assuming your variable is called `products` you can do:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <h1>{{product.title}}</h1>
    <h1>Bundles:</h1>
    {% for bundle in product.productbundle_set.all %}
        <h2>{{bundle.quantity}}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I want to use that products in template to show all product then there productbundle. how can i do that?

Comment: Updated for a template usage.

Comment: thanks for update but this query is not working because I have two foreign key from product. how can i access that now?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `related_name` of `product` inside `ProductBundle` to something like `bundles` and then you can go `product.bundles.all()` to access all `ProductBundle` related to a `Product`

**edit to filter all products if they have a `ProductBundle`**

assuming you are using `bundles` as `related_name`:
`Product.objects.filter(bundles__isnull=False).distinct()`

Comment: If we consider this thing in SQL so if I make join with product and productbundle I can get list of products with product bundle. How can i do that in Django

Comment: do you mean to find all products which have at least one productbundle?

Comment: all product then if they have productbundle then those product can include that productbundle too. like left join in sql between product and productbundle

Comment: I edited the answer with what I guess you are asking