# Fetch all record from model and it's related model

Tags: django, django-models

Say for example I have two table, Author and Books.

```
class Author (models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Book (models.Model ):
    author_id = models.ForeignKey('Author')
    book_name = models.CharField(...)
```

Author table will contain the entry of authors irrespective of if they have written any book. And also one author can have multiples books.
So I want to query all the authors name with their respective written books ( containing book_name ) even if they haven't written any book.

Output

```
author_name    book_name
 author1         book1
 author1         book2
 author2         None
 author3         book3
           ...
 author22       book33
```

Comment: yes , but also want its related book details

Comment: If you want to return the author books you can do `Book.objects.filter(author__name="name")`

Comment: So, does it means that it cannot be done in single query ?

Comment: What is your filter in this situation? You can do`Book.objects.all()` if you don t have any filter

Comment: I have seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632710/fetch-child-data-with-parents-in-django-queries . Let me try

Comment: It loops over the product model and call set method on related model, will it hit the database on each loop ?